# Git ignore all files except *.py but also ignore script.py

Tags: git

I want to ignore all files except those with .py extension, but also I want to ignore some file script.py.
I tried these .gitignore:

```
*
!*/
!.gitignore
!*.py
script.py
```

and this:

```
script.py
*
!*/
!.gitignore
!*.py
```

and this:

```
*
script.py
!*/
!.gitignore
!*.py
```

They don't work - script.py is not ignored. What should I do?

Comment: may be you put incorrect path to script.py file

Comment: no, script.py in the main folder of the git

Comment: Also, I tested the new .gitignore using `git reset . ; git add . ; git status`

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that script.py is already tracked. If script.py is already tracked, .gitignore won't make a difference. You would have to remove it first (that is, moving forward, cause previous revisions will have it... unless you rewrite history).

```
git remove --cached script.py
git commit -m "blahblah"
# now the file will be ignored
```

And this should work in .gitignore, to the best of my knowledge (`TTBOMK` is valid acronym?)

```
*
!*.py
script.py
```